# File sharing violation trying to Verify a SqlCe database

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

When I execute the following line of code, I get the exception cited below it:

```
if (!engine.Verify(VerifyOption.Default))

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

I am using EF. Every single use of my `DataMonitorDbContext` is wrapped in a `using` block. I even get the same error if I make a small console app with absolutely only the following code in it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data source=C:\\Development\\DataMonSol\\Code\\DataMonitor.ControlPanel\\bin\\Debug\\Database\\MonitorData.sdf");
        if (!engine.Verify(VerifyOption.Default))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Corrupt");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
            engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverAllPossibleRows);
        }
    }
```

With no other code using the damned DB.

Comment: First chance exceptions are allowed to happen have you checked your debug settings

Comment: Even when Exceptions set to break when no exceptions occur, I still get a file sharing exception. On Break when Thrown, I get it at `Verify`, With Break when Thrown off, it gives me a line x col y exception in the MainWindow constructor. I put it there so no other files could get to it first.

Comment: Why is the DB becoming corrupt every five seconds? I'm only doing inserts.